# Android application with Jedis

Tags: android, redis, jedis

I don't know whether my question makes sense or not. But here is what I have done. 
First trial with Java application:
- I created sample Java project.
- Added jedis jar file to it.
- Established a connection like,

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("my IP address");
    jedis.connect();
    String value = jedis.get("foo"); //I have set the value for "foo" in redis
    System.out.println(value); //successfully prints foo in console when ran as Java application
```

Now I tried the same thing in Android application, but it failed

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_jedis);
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("my IP address");
    jedis.connect();
    String value = jedis.get("foo");
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(value);
```

My aim is to get the data from Redis and display it in my Android application. Please help !

Comment: So what issue are you getting?

Comment: When I run the application I'm getting the following error in error logcat....

01-21 23:25:10.838: E/AndroidRuntime(966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-21 23:25:10.838: E/AndroidRuntime(966): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved. I have added user-permissions for INTERNET in manifest file. Its working fine now. Thanks to all !

Answer (score 0):

Did you import it into the Eclipse project??

Right clic in the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add external JAR or other type you want...  And active it into the "Order and export" tab...

Comment: I did the same.
Added jedis jar file and when I run it I got the following error in logcat....

01-21 23:25:10.838: E/AndroidRuntime(966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 23:25:10.838: E/AndroidRuntime(966): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis.clients.jedis.Jedis